# Can't find PInvoke DLL on Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, pinvoke, native-code

I am working on Windows Mobile application.

Whenever I download some sample which is using wrapper around native code (using DllImport), it always gives "Can't find PInvoke DLL" error.

I am using VS 2005 with C# on 64-bit Windows 7 OS.

I have checked many of solution on stackoverflow as well as othersites, but with no solution to my problem.

If its 64-bit OS problem, what are the steps to get that dll compiled for 64-bit? I tried to change platform to x64 through Configuration Manager, but not working.

Comment: MAPIlib.dll used by http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows/PocketPCandSmartphone.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

What are you talking about with 64-bit?  All WinMo and WinCE devices are 32-bit.  Did you build MAPILib.dll?  Is it on the device in a folder where the loader can find it (like \Windows)?  Did you build MAPILib for the correct processor/OS (i.e. you didn't build it for the desktop)?

Comment: The problem is resolved. The download does not contain MAPILib.ddl file. It was generated when I ran it for the first time and gave error (I don't know why). And from second time it was running successfully without error.